# ASP.NET with jQuery popup dialog: how to post back on dialog closing

Tags: jquery, asp.net, updatepanel, jquery-ui-dialog, asynchronous-postback

I'm working on a rather complicated site.  We have an update panel that contains some controls.  When one of the controls is clicked, a jQuery dialog box opens.

When the dialog box closes, I want to signal the update panel to change its display.  To do that I need to post back to the update panel.

I know the dialog box has a handy callback event that you can hook up to.  But here's the thing.  The javascript that manipulates the dialog is all in a separate .js file.  I want to continue keeping it separate.  So the code that does the postback has either be in that .js file, or injected as a parameter into some method in the .js file.

How can I do that?  And what would I pass to the .js file methods?

Comment: You can extend the function in the js file to receive a callback function for each method from the dialog box that needs hooking into; then just wire up those functions, but check them first: if (typeof(cbFncClose) === 'function') cbFncClose();

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just had to solve this recently.  I have a generic function to help with the issue.

- Put a hidden `asp:button` within the `UpdatePanel` or outside and set it as an `AsyncPostBackTrigger`.
- Call the js function from `ItemDataBound` if needed, passing in the `ClientID` of the hidden `asp:button`.
- The js function will call the click event on the button passed in once the "OK" or whatever you set `buttonTxt` to, button is clicked.
- You can then handle the `UpdatePanel.Update` automatically if the button is inside the `UpdatePanel` or call `Update` within the `butHidden_Click`.

**Markup:**

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1">
  <ContentTemplate>
     <asp:button id="btnHidden" style="display:none" runat="server" onclick="btnHidden_Click"/>
   </ContentTemplate>
 </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

**Script:**

```
   function showjQueryUIDialogOkBtnCallback(buttonToClick, dialogSelector, buttonTxt, isModal, width, height) 
   {
       var buttonOpts = {};
       buttonOpts[buttonTxt] = function () {
           $("#" + buttonToClick).trigger('click');
       };

       buttonOpts['Cancel'] = function () {
           $(this).dialog("close");
           $(this).dialog('destroy'); 
       }

       $(dialogSelector).dialog({
           resizable: false,
           height: height,
           width: width,
           modal: isModal,
           open: function (type, data) {
               $(this).parent().appendTo("form"); //won't postback unless within the form tag
           },
           buttons: buttonOpts

       });

       $(dialogSelector).dialog('open');

    }
```

Comment: Very ingenious!  Thank you!  I wasn't keen at first on having a hidden button that only gets clicked through script, but I can see that, given the complications of posting back AND an update panel, this might be the most reliable solution.  Thanks again!

Comment: That does works great!  Finally!  Took me 2 days to get this to work (with fiddling and with google surfing). Thanks for the posted answered code that works.